# How to send POST data through HttpClient and get the result of it after sending it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to obtain a published data from a ASP.NET file who publish all the data related to certain string i send in POST format.

The web-service is working fine and i already do the necesary test to see if is working properly.

Is valid mention than before the web-server was publishing all the data just fine, but i now want to add this aditional filter layer, to optimize the readings of the android app when reading the publication.

Here is the code of the method i use to get the data (who used to work just fine) but now i'm also using it to send a string to obtain certain specific data, and doesn't seems to work:

```
namespace AndroidApp.REST
{
    public static class Client
    {
        public async static Task<T> GetRequest<T>(this string url)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                //Preparing to have something to read
                var stringContent = new StringContent("someHardCodedStringToTellTheServerToPublishTheDataTheAppWillConsume");
                var sending = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);

                //Reading data
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Any question, comment, request for clarification or anything than helps to obtain an answer or improve the clarity of the question would be much apreciated too

Thanks in advance

Comment: The url accepts the data to be passed in certain format such as JSON? In that case you need to pass header "Content-Type" also while making request.

Comment: not really, just as simple as a string, the idea of the string is not being data by itself, but to define the behaviour of the server of the rest of the data sended.

Comment: What you are getting back as a response?

Comment: You don't need to send a GET request after you send your POST request. The `PostAsync` method returns an HttpResponseMessage (wrapped in a task), so you get the web servers response to your POST from that object. I think in your example you are looking for `sending.Content`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya a string which is a Json array of objects than is consumed by the aplication after the data is sent.

Comment: And that JSON array is not what you expected? Btw what @Alex has mentioned is also true. Any reason you need to do POST first and then GET? Is it like in POST you are telling service what to return when the next GET call is made?

Comment: @Alex could it be, but doesn't work just use the PostAsync method, what do you mean with sending.Content?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the JSON array is what i need, but not what i send, the problem is the app is not consuming in it, it used to consume it perfectly before when the ASP.net do not requeire any previous data to publish the info, now i want to add the feature than, after receive certain info through post, it return the JSON array, which it does (i test it with a chrome plugin) but the httpClient is not returning the JSON array back to the cellphone (like used to be, when i was just using GetAsync(url)).

Comment: @Obsdarek I'm talking about your variable named `sending`. It should be an `HttpResponseMessage` object, so it will have a property named `Content`. What is the value of that property?

Comment: @Alex i think is empty, here is the result http://imgur.com/a/BmLtt